# Using AsyncTask in AlertDialog brings out lagging UX?

Tags: android, performance, android-asynctask, android-alertdialog

I know this is a kind of weird title to describe the question. I have a code as below:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).setView(myScrollView)
.setPositiveButton("Sent Query", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
     dialog.cancel();
try {
     JSONStringURL = myURL_here;
     image = new AsyncTaskParseJson1(JSONStringURL).execute().get();
if (image.size() == 0) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "no data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} else {
    overlayImage(image);
}
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
}
}.show();
```

when i press "Positive Button", the app should cancel the AlertDialog immediately, and then execute the AsyncTask. Unfortunately, the AlertDialog will lag for 3~4 sec and then run the AsyncTask makes the UX feel really bad, but i have no idea why it will lag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NEVER` use `AsyncTask.get()`.  That makes you wait for the task to finish, which totally ruins the idea of it being asynchronous.  The fact the function even exists is a design flaw in Android.  Instead, anything that needs to be done after the `AsyncTask` finishes should be done in `onPostExecute()` of the task (or in a function called from there).

Obviously this is your problem-  you aren't closing the dialog and doing the task in parallel, you're waiting for the task to finish (remember the `UI` will not update until control is returned to the UI thread looper).

Comment: thanks bro! i know what u mean, so how do i close the dialog and do the task in parallel? thx!

Comment: Remove the call to .get-  just call .execute.  Then put the code that uses the result in onPostExecute of the task.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use these changes

```
dialog.dismiss();
```

In place of

```
 dialog.cancel();
```